# Adding XML file to a SOAP request

Tags: android, xml, soap, ksoap2

(i'm trying to say hello, but the site keeps deleting it oO)... ! 
Here is my question : I found out how to send a request to a webservice using ksoap, but i still cannot figure out where to add my XML to the request !
Here is my code :

```
    public static SoapObject soap () throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
    request.addProperty(toto, HERE IS MY XML);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope (
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject (request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE (URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true; 
    androidHttpTransport.call (SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse ();
    return soapResult;
}
```

If i delete the "request.addProperty line", it reaches the server, but it does nothing, because i need to send my XML. If someone know how to do that, it would definitely make my day !!

Thanks you for reading this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it doesn't help you with this particular issue, but I would not recommended using ksoap. I wasted so much time getting it to work and after that I wrote my SOAP client with few hours and it works without problem.

It's easy:

```
public static HashMap<String, Object> callSOAPServer(StringBuffer soap /* YOUR XML GOES HERE*/,String action) {
    HashMap<String, Object> xMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    byte[] result = null;              
    byte[] data = new byte[1024*1024];  
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); /* Your probably need to edit client for your needs, like timeout, scheme, etc */
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataInputStream is = null;
    boolean download = true;
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(/* YOUR URL GOES HERE */ );
    httppost.setHeader("soapaction", action);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");     
    try {               
         HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(soap.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);
         httppost.setEntity(entity);  
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
         if (r_entity != null) {                    
             result = new byte[(int) r_entity.getContentLength()];      
             size = result.length;                 
             if (r_entity.isStreaming()) {                      
                is = new DataInputStream(r_entity.getContent());     
                while((count = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {                      
                        buffer.write(data, 0, count);
                        total +=count;                    
                    }
             }
             buffer.flush();
             result = buffer.toByteArray();
             data = null;
             buffer = null;                
          }             
     } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
     }          
     if(result !=null){             
        try {
            String sb;
            String sn;              
            sb = new String(result, "UTF-8");
            sn = sb.replace("&amp;", "AMP"); //Precaution for SAX parser
            result = sn.getBytes();     
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } 
            xMap.put(STATUS, "OK");
            xMap.put(SOAP, result);        
        }else{
            if(xMap.get(STATUS) == null) {
                xMap.put(STATUS, "ERROR");
            }   
        }           
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 
        return xMap;        
  }
```

Here is parser:

```
public ArrayList< HashMap<String,String>> parseSoap (byte[] soapResult,String soapFunctionName, String... args) {       
        ArrayList< HashMap<String,String>> xMap = new ArrayList< HashMap<String,String>>();         
        if(soapResult == null) xMap.put(STATUS, "Where is stuff to handle");
        byte[] initReqrepsonse = soapResult;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(initReqrepsonse);

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            if(soapFunctionName.equals(NEWS)) { /*IF YOU USE MULTIPLE SOAP FUNCTION, YOU NEED TO DETERMINE WHICH IS WHICH...*/
               NewsXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new NewsXMLHandler(); /*..BECAUSE HERE YOU NEED TO SPECIFY FIELDS WHICH YOU WANT TO RETRIEVE FROM XML*/
               xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
               xr.parse(new InputSource(bais));
               xMap.put(SOAP_OUTPUT, myXMLHandler.getOutput());
               myXMLHandler = null;
             }
             sp = null;
             xr = null;
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
          spf = null;
      return xMap;
 }
```

And for that thing (NewsXMLHandler) which determines which fields you want to parse:

```
public class NewsXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

public NewsXMLHandler() {}

private ArrayList< HashMap<String,String> > data;   

private HashMap<String,String> dataHash;

private final StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

private boolean bStore = false;

ArrayList< HashMap<String,String>>  getOutput() {
    return data;
}


@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException 
{
    data = new ArrayList< HashMap<String,String> >();

}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException
{

}

@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    mStringBuilder.setLength(0);
    bStore = true;      
    try { 
        //HERE YOU NEED TO SPECIFY WHICH IS ROOT NODE OF XML FROM SOAP, IN MY EXPERIENCE ITS OUT
          if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("out")) {
             dataHash = new HashMap<String,String>();
         }          

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.d("error in startElement", e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
}
@Override

public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException 
{
        bStore = false;         

        //HERE IT IS, JUST WRITE NAME OF NODE WHICH YOU WANT TO USE FOR YOUR APPLICATION        
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("your node name"))
        {               
            dataHash.put("your node name", mStringBuilder.toString().trim());           
        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("your node name 2"))
        {               
            dataHash.put("your node name 2", mStringBuilder.toString().trim());         
        }

        // CONTINUE WITH THOSE IFS UNTIL YOU HAVE ALL FIELDS WHICH YOU NEED COVERED

        // HERE YOU WRAP ALL OF THOSE HIGHER NODE AND SAVE TO ARRAYLIST, SO IF THERE ARE MORE OF THEM, YOU GET THEM ALL - AGAIN ITS NAME OF ROOT NODE 
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("out")) {
            data.add(dataHash);
            dataHash = null;
        } 

}
@Override

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
{

    if (bStore) 
    {   
        mStringBuilder.append(ch, start, length);
        if(mStringBuilder.length() == 0)  mStringBuilder.setLength(0);            

    }
}
}
```

And here goes the usage. As it seems you alredy figured out, you can't execute URL request on main thread. You just need to use AsyncTask, Service, IntentService, etc. I am not going to cover it here. I like to use IntentService and save entries to database.

So lets say, you wrap those two static function in class SOAPHandler:

```
HashMap<String, Object> SOAPResponse = SOAPHandler.callSOAPSERVER(/*YOUR XML REQUEST HERE*/, /*NAME OF SOAP METHOD ON SERVER*/)
ArrayList< HashMap<String,String>> parsedEntries = SOAPHandler.parseSoap(SOAPResponse, NEWS, NULL);

foreach(HashMap<String,String> hash : parsedEntries) {
       String entryOne = hash.get("your node name");
       String entryTwo = hash.get("your node name 2");
       //HERE YOU HAVE YOUR STRINGS, DO WHATEVER WITH THEM
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if ksoap become too boring to use, i'm going to use something like this ! You use SAXparser to parse the result ? is it easy ?

Comment: Yes its easy, I have a code if you want that. Just comment here, if you need it and I post it. I don't know about your experience, but many times I receive somewhat less than ideal response from WS and I need to adjust it slightly to work. This situation is easily solvable by having custom SAX parser. Ksoap, does a pretty poor job in this regard, not the mention, if you want to use SSL, Ksoap is basically useless for older Android SDKs.

Comment: Well, that's my first experience with webservices (and with android by the way). If you don't mind posting your SAXparser code, i would be glad to see it ! thank you

Comment: It was also my start point with Android. Its probably good to mention, that I have pretty extensive Java knowledge, but it does not matter that much, because its mainly the SDK, not programming language itself, which is hard to learn when you are beginner. I was really furious about Ksoap for long nights when it doesn't do what I wanted. I learned long ago, thats it better to write stuff by myself than rely on libraries without good support. I'll edit my post right away.

Comment: So here you go, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Basic KSOAP Android tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html#more), which should greatly assist with understanding how to use KSOAP to consume a web service.

What is important to note, is that you will not be able to send a raw xml packet using KSOAP but that the parameters need to be passed as PropertyInfo class instances.

HTH

Comment: Thank you, this is going to help me